# Play framework 2.0 - Ebean @OneToOne "user - details"

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I need some help please.
I have two classes **user** and **details** on a @OneToOne relationship

```
public class User extends Model {

@Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String username;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public OwnerDetail ownerDetails;
```

and

```
public class OwnerDetail extends Model {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public User user;

    public String fname;
    public String lname;
```

What query am I supposed to run in the User model in order to get the details and in the html/template file to be able to use: `@user.ownerDetails.fname` or am I approaching this the wrong way?

The query that I am currently running is below, and in the console I see the correct sql generated but I still cannot do `@user.ownerDetails.fname`.

```
public static User findByUsername(String email) {
    User user = find.fetch("ownerDetails").​where()
        .eq("username", email)
        .findUnique();
}
```

Comment: Not the solution, but i think your @JoinColumn is incorrect ("user_id" doesn't exist anywhere)

Comment: Good point Julien but even after adding the user_id it doesn't work. I can see the correct query being generated though - that's what's frustrating. I feel like there something stupid that I am overlooking or maybe something with the @OneToOne mapping?!

Comment: Show the code of your controller AND view to help you...